# How do you make different layers of images in background?

Tags: html, web, header, background

I wanted to know what code is used to make a background like this http://www.wareztuga.ws/

What if i want to make a  to put a header like that? What code should i use?

I appreciate you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "different layers".

Do you mean how the flags change from dim to bright?  They are just using css3 opacity filter

Something like this:

```
.class{  filter:alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1.0; -khtml-opacity:1.0; opacity:1.0; }
.class:hover{  filter:alpha(opacity=70); -moz-opacity:0.7; -khtml-opacity:0.7; opacity:0.7;
```

If you want to have an image change when you hover over it, you can use the css background-postion filter.

Let's say you have an image that is 20px Wide and 20px High.  In photoshop, double the canvas height, and put second image above it.  Then in css do something like:

```
.class{ height:20px; width:20px; background:url('your/image.png'); background-position:0px 0px; }
.class:hover{ background-position:0px -20px; } //or 20px depending on what way you want to move your background image.
```

Still now sure if that answers your questions.

Otherwise, the "layers" are just divs with background images set.  And then children divs with different images set.

Comment: the layers i was talking about are the diferente colors in the background

Comment: Other thing i need is a table that has no limits from right side and left side, and only limited by pixels in the upper line and in the down one

Comment: langel, you should ask a separate question.  This helps other people when they are searching google or stackoverflow for the same question.  It is hard to find questions in the comments. But to answer your question, search for the CSS operator white-space:nowrap;